# Class for calculating arbitrarily large numbers?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there might not be a class that would allow as much accuracy as there is memory. With overloaded operators in order to do arithmetic on it as if it was a normal number.

Ex:

```
BigNumber num;

num = 8;
for(int i = 0; i < 5000000; ++i)
{
   num *= num;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: 64 bit integers are not big enough for you ?

Comment: @Paul, There are plenty of applications where 64-bit integers are insufficient.

Comment: @bdonlan: indeed, but the question says "as much accuracy as there is memory", which although is ambiguous, I take to mean that if you have a 64 bit address space he would want 64 bit integers. And the example above suggests that 5000000 would be considered "big". But maybe I misunderstood the question ?

Comment: @Paul R: the example suggests that 8 to the power of 5000000 is a big number

Comment: @Paul what I meant was, an int occupies 4 bytes, and so I might want a number which consumes 1GB of ram.

Comment: @Milo: OK - I see now - so you just want a BigNum library that supports very large integer widths. However since there are only something like 10^80 atoms in the universe I'm not sure why you'd want integers that are 8 G bits in width, but I guess you have your reasons..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are plenty libraries for that, like [GMP (it provides also a C++ interface)](http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General.html) or [cbignum](http://www.imach.uran.ru/cbignum/).

You'll probably find as many libraries of this kind as you wish.