# Print nth Fibonacci number [upto 1000 digits]

Tags: c++, c, fibonacci

How can one calculate nth Fibonacci number in **C/C++**? The Fibonacci number can contain upto 1000 digits. I can generate numbers upto 2^64 (unsigned long long). Since that is the limit of numbers, so I am guessing there has to be some other way of doing it - which I do not know of.

**EDIT:**

Also, it has to be done without using any external libraries.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Use a BigInt library? See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055661/bigint-bigbit-library

Comment: What problems have you run up against?

Comment: It's not a good idea to look for solution for [Project Euler problems](http://projecteuler.net/problem=25). It's against their policy.

Comment: See this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907806/class-for-calculating-arbitrarily-large-numbers

Comment: @YuHao I do not solve Project Euler problems. It is a question I found somewhere else. Anyway, the question you have mentioned is not exactly the same.

Comment: Use the awesome power of mathematics! Seriously, how would you do it using a pencil and a piece of paper?

Comment: @YuHao I *thought* it looked familiar ...

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&list=PL37ZVnwpeshF7AHpbZt33aW0brYJyNftx&v=j_EfPW4G-L0 - awesome talk by Angus Croll from twitter on coding in literary styles, using javascript to do Fibonacci in different ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give a few hints since you haven't indicated that you've started yet.

A thousand digits is a lot.  More than any built-in numeric type in C or C++ can hold.

One way to get around it is to use an arbitrary-precision math library.  This will have constructs that will give you basically as many digits as you want in your numbers.

Another way is to roll your own cache-and-carry:

```
unsigned short int term1[1024];  // 1024 digits from 0-9
unsigned short int term2[1024];  // and another

unsigned short int sum[1024];    // the sum

addBigNumbers(&term1, &term2, &sum);   // exercise for the reader
```

I'd expect the algorithm for `addBigNumbers` to go something like this:

```
Start at the ones digit (index 0)
Add term1[0] and term2[0]
Replace sum[0] with the right digit of term1[0] + term2[0] (which is ... ?)
Keep track of the carry (how?) and use it in the next iteration (how?)
Repeat for each digit
```

Now, since you're calculating a Fibonacci sequence, you'll be able to re-use these big numbers to get to the next term in the sequence.  You might find that it's faster not to copy them around but to just change which ones are the terms and which one is the sum on your repeated calls to `addBigNumbers`.

Comment: So after making this add function, I apply the basic Fibonacci formula: a=1, b=1; a+=b; b+=a; ?

Comment: More like: a = 1, b = 1, c = a + b, a' = b + c, b' = c + a', etc.

Comment: @John: unsigned int, to store a single digit in? `char` is more appropriate, although I would probably try and halve even that ;-)

Comment: @Jongware Absolutely correct, and if I were implementing it, I'd do that, too. If C or C++ had a type called `byte` I would have used that in a heartbeat. But for teaching purposes, I felt that using `unsigned short int` was clearer than needing to explain: "You're actually storing the `char` whose value is 0, not the character '0' ... but you *can* store the characters if you want, you just have to remember to subtract 48 from the ASCII value to get the actual digit ..." See what I mean? :)  Yeah, I'm wasting space, but I'll let the OP optimize if s/he needs. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) for arbitrarily large integers.

Comment: I have updated the question now. It has to be done without using any external libraries.